# How to verify (unnested) row count of huge nested table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that according to the Google Big Query GUI has `353340737871 rows`(around 353 billion) and the following schema:

```
Field name   Type       Mode       Description
TS           TIMESTAMP  REQUIRED    
QR           STRING     REQUIRED    
RCDS         RECORD     REPEATED    
RCDS. COL1   STRING     REQUIRED    
RCDS. COL2   STRING     REQUIRED    
RCDS. COL3   STRING     REQUIRED    
RCDS. COL4   STRING     REQUIRED
```

Now if I run:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    my_dataset.my_table
    ,UNNEST(RCDS)
```

it will return `1495670921285 rows`(around 1.5 trillion).

Is it safe to assume that's all the data there is if the table's collections were flattened?

Is there another way to verify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you consider flattened: what if an array is empty? Do you want to keep the row or not?

If you want to keep it, you have to `LEFT JOIN` - if you want to drop it you can leave it at your version with `,` or `CROSS JOIN`.

A more performant version of the `cross join` would be to just sum up the array lengths:

```sql
SELECT
  SUM( ARRAY_LENGTH(RCDS) )
FROM ...
```

whereas for a left join you'd have to make sure to add a 1 to the sum in case array_length returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is missing data rows when RCDS is empty. LEFT JOIN gives you more rows with RCDS.* being NULL.

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    my_dataset.my_table
    LEFT JOIN UNNEST(RCDS)
```